# VB.net ADO commit DataGridView changes, code-only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, commit

I need to commit the changes in my DataGridView to disk. btnSave_Click() below throws this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.'
What should I really be doing here? If I add records to the DataGridView or delete rows from it, will those changes also be committed to disk?

The form on which this is based simply asks the user for an SQL statement then executes it in btnTest_Click(). This is just an experiment to learn how to do more complex stuff in my real application.  Production code WILL NOT allow SQL injection.

'OS: Windows 10
'Language: Visual Basic 2022
'Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.8
'Target CPU: x64
'NuGet package: system.data.oledb
'Database: Access 2019 64-bit
'Projects - Add Reference - "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library"

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim BooksConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " _
+ "Data Source = D:\My Docs\BooksDb.accdb")
Dim ResultsCommand As OleDbCommand = Nothing
Dim ResultsAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ResultsTable As New DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
BooksConnection.Open()
txtSQLtester.Text = "SELECT * FROM Authors"
End Sub

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    BooksConnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Try
        ResultsCommand = New OleDbCommand(txtSQLtester.Text, BooksConnection)
        ResultsAdapter.SelectCommand = ResultsCommand
        ResultsAdapter.Fill(ResultsTable)
        grdSQLtester.DataSource = ResultsTable
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("SQL statement didn't work", vbOKOnly, "SQL ERROR")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ResultsCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ResultsAdapter.Update(ResultsTable)
End Sub
```

End Class

'----------------------------------------
' Below is the complete solution, including handling added rows and deleted rows
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim BooksConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " _
+ "Data Source = D:\My Docs\BooksDb.accdb")
Dim ResultsCommand As OleDbCommand = Nothing
Dim ResultsAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ResultsTable As New DataTable
Dim ResultsDataSet As New DataSet ' can accomodate multiple tables
Dim strTableName As String = "Authors"
Dim lstDeletedIDs As New List(Of Long) ' record the AU_ID of each row deleted
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
BooksConnection.Open()
txtSQLtester.Text = "SELECT * FROM " + strTableName
End Sub

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    BooksConnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Try
        ResultsCommand = New OleDbCommand(txtSQLtester.Text, BooksConnection)
        ResultsAdapter.SelectCommand = ResultsCommand
        ResultsAdapter.Fill(ResultsTable)
        grdSQLtester.DataSource = ResultsTable 
        ResultsCommand.Dispose() 
        strMode = "DataTable"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("SQL statement didn't work", vbOKOnly, "SQL ERROR")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ' If grdSQLtester. only if something changed
    Dim strCmd As String, row As Integer
        For row = 0 To grdSQLtester.Rows.Count() - 2 ' Automatic new row at end is useless and throws errors
            With grdSQLtester.Rows(row).Cells
                Debug.Print("Row=" + row.ToString + " Au_ID=" + .Item("Au_ID").Value.ToString)
                If .Item("Au_ID").Value.ToString = "" Then ' This is a new record
                    If Len(Trim(.Item("Author").Value.ToString)) < 1 Then ' Just an empty record
                    Else ' Real data to append
                        strCmd = "INSERT INTO " + strTableName _
                        + "(Author,Year_Born) VALUES " _
                        + "('" + .Item("Author").Value.ToString + "'" _
                        + "," + .Item("Year_Born").Value.ToString + ")"
                    End If
                Else ' This is an UPDATE to an existing record
                    strCmd = "UPDATE " + strTableName + " SET" _
                    + "  Author = '" + .Item("Author").Value.ToString + "'" _
                    + ", Year_Born = " + .Item("Year_Born").Value.ToString _
                    + "  WHERE Au_ID = " + .Item("Au_ID").Value.ToString
                End If
            End With
            Debug.Print("Row=" + row.ToString + "strCmd=" + strCmd)
            ExecuteSQL(strCmd)
        Next row
        For Each D In lstDeletedIDs ' These need deleted
            strCmd = " DELETE FROM " + strTableName + " WHERE Au_ID = " + D.ToString
            Debug.Print("Delete SQL: " + strCmd)
            ExecuteSQL(strCmd)
        Next
End Sub

Sub ExecuteSQL(strCmd As String)
    ResultsCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCmd, BooksConnection)
    ResultsAdapter.SelectCommand = ResultsCommand
    ResultsCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() ' Execute an SQL command that does not fetch data
    ResultsCommand.Dispose() ' At this point it has useless data and may be release and reuwed
End Sub

Private Sub grdSQLtester_UserDeletingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles grdSQLtester.UserDeletingRow
    ' Remember the AU_ID of each row deleted from the DataGridView so we can delete it from the table on disk
    Dim ID As Long = e.Row.Cells.Item("au_ID").Value
    Debug.Print("Deleting AU_ID = " + ID.ToString)
    lstDeletedIDs.Add(ID)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Well... the error message really does give you the info.  You're calling ResultsAdapter.Update(ResultsTable) but haven't specified the UpdateCommand property.  Noticed you are explicitly setting the SelectCommand directly in the method above, so really just the next step on is missing.

Comment: @Hursey So, I create a separate SQL statement to update each changed record?  That sort of defeats the purpose of fetching an entire recordset to edit perhaps a few or just one record, does it not?  I'm pretty new to the whole SQL scene and just don't see what you consider obvious.

Comment: No, you're using a table adapter, it just needs to know what you expect to happen when firing the update method.  Maybe a read over [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/update-data-by-using-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) might help

Comment: No, you don't write a separate SQL statement for each record. You write one SQL statement and it is used for every record. It should be obvious that you need at least one SQL statement. You can't make changes to a database with no SQL at all. If you do some proper reading about the `OleDbDataAdapter` class that you're using then you can learn how to use it properly. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) are some ADO.NET (not ADO, which is a different thing) examples I created some time ago.

Comment: Note that you can also use a command builder to generate the SQL for you, if certain conditions are met. There's an example of that in my link above too. For the record, experienced developers will rarely do that, but experienced developers are probably not using ADO.NET directly these days anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yeah, I know, do it in a loop.  And I have to detect new rows and deleted rows.  I've made it function, but that was an awful lot of work when READING the data into the DataGridView was sooo easy - I was expecting that writing it out (with adds and deletes) would be just as easy.  And figuring it out for ADO, when sooo much info out there assumes SQL Server of some kind, was frustrating.  Thank you, and thanks to Hursey, for the hints.  I have added my entire solution to the original post for reference by others.

Comment: *"I know, do it in a loop"*. If that's what you think then you don't know at all. *"I was expecting that writing it out (with adds and deletes) would be just as easy"*. It is. To retrieve data you create the `SelectCommand` command and call `Fill`. To save changes, you create the `InsertCommand` and/or `UpdateCommand` and/or `DeleteCommand` and call `Update`. If you don't know that now then you must not have bothered to follow or read the link I provided. The fifth and sixth examples there demonstrate, exactly this, creating the commands explicitly and using a command builder respectively.